# torch in-place operations to save memory (softmax)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch

Some operations in torch are executed in-place. Shorthand operators like += for example.

Is it possible to get in-place execution for other operations, such as [`softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#softmax)?

I'm currently working with language processing. The model produces a long sequence of probability distributions over a large vocabulary. This final output tensor is responsible for ca 60% of allocated memory. Which is a huge problem, since I need to calculate a softmax over it and that doubles the required memory.

Here is an example of the problem. I am not interested in the tensor t, only in its softmax:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

t = torch.tensor(np.zeros((30000,30000))).cuda()  #allocates 6.71 GB of GPU
softmax = F.softmax(t, 1)  #out of memory error
del t  #too late, program crashed
```

Even the following doesn't work:

```
F.softmax(torch.tensor(np.zeros((30000,30000))).cuda(), 1)
```

Comment: I don't know of a way applying the softmax in-place. But in your example here you could just split your tensor (i.e. into 2 or 4 pieces) and then apply the softmax on these on after another. Also when having only 2 or 4 *"batches"* it shouldn't be that much slower. Just as an alternative :)

Comment: that's what I'm doing ;) (but it would be really nice to have it in one clean operation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created an in-place version of softmax:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# in-place version
t = torch.tensor(np.ones((100,200)))
torch.exp(t, out=t)
summed = torch.sum(t, dim=1, keepdim=True)
t /= summed

# original version
t2 = torch.tensor(np.ones((100,200)))
softmax = F.softmax(t2, 1)

assert torch.allclose(t, softmax)
```

To answer my question: If you want in-place functions, you have to create them yourself by plugging together low-level operations:

- many functions such as [`torch.exp`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.exp) can be given an optional `out` parameter.
- assignments `t[idx] = something` are in-place
- shorthand operators `/=`, `*=`, `+=`, `-=` are in-place

This requires careful debugging and can be non-intuitive:

```
t = t / summed  #not in-place
t /= summed  #in-place
```

I've read that in-place operations can produce problems with gradients. I'll do some more testing with this code.

Comment: This is great, I couldn't find the `out` parameter mentioned anywhere. As a minor thing, it may be more numerically stable to subtract logsumexp(t) before the exp rather than dividing by the sum after.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with PyTorch as of current. You can try to roll your own [GPU kernel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html) but I see trouble  (if not a wall) ahead, which is likely the reason why this operation isn't available in the first place.

Softmax can be easily applied in parallel except for normalization, which requires a reduction. Reductions are nontrivial and they can be either in-place *or* parallel (keeping in mind that use of atomics amounts to concurrent-but-not-parallel operation). This means that your in-place operation would have to either allocate under the hood anyway, which defeats the purpose, or run awfully slow. Please consider my answer as somewhat speculative, I am not an expert on GPGPU, but my point is that it is at least a difficult problem to solve cheaply, fast and correctly.

That being said, if you only care about the softmax, it sounds to me like you're doing inference. And perhaps it is a viable choice for your application to move the logits to CPU and run softmax there, while your GPU already processes the next batch?

Comment: I don't know the internals of a typical softmax implementation. That being said, I don't see why we would have to allocate two arrays: The exp can be done in-place, the sum doesn't require a lot of memory

Comment: The reduction only requires one entry for every sum. So if we allocate that, it's many orders of magnitude smaller than the original tensor